Lots of Asynchronous Message Consumers with selector JMSCorrelationID='CamelDummyJmsMessageSelector'
I am using apache camel to configure jms request/reply pattern with spring-jms and ibm-mq.
My Camel Route is configured as InOut pattern and I am able to read the message from Reply queue successfully after sending a message to the Request queue.
However after the message is successfully processed, There is a background camel thread running  which is creating message consumers for the same reply queue that is already processed. The below log messages are being written infinitely.
After the reply is received, I am not able to understand why
additional threads are still trying to consume the message. In my case, I will get only 1 message back from the reply queue.
Our MQ administrator also mentioned that, there are many asynchronous consumers being created on the queue and are in SUSPENDED state.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=reference-display-qstatus-display-queue-status
While debugging, I understood that code is entering into the below method, but not sure in which scenario the process will terminate.
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.AsyncMessageListenerInvoker#executeOngoingLoop
26-08-2024 13:42:55.270 [Camel (camel-1) thread #6 - QueueReplyManager["TEST"]] TRACE org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.SharedQueueMessageListenerContainer: Consumer [Cached JMS MessageConsumer: com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQQueueReceiver@3a9df93c] of session [Cached JMS Session: {"ConnectionId":"C3E2D8C3D4D8E4F14040404040404040DF9A9ECAB3810001","ObjectId":"com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQSession@593ea8be","Channel":"TEST","Port":"1431","ConnectionMode":"WMQ_CM_CLIENT","Host":"CHUBBHOST1.chubb.com/10.64.25.1","ResolvedQueueManager":"MQU1","QueueManager":"MQU1"}] did not receive a message
26-08-2024 13:42:55.270 [Camel (camel-1) thread #6 - QueueReplyManager["TEST"]] TRACE org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.SharedQueueMessageListenerContainer: runningAllowed() -> true
26-08-2024 13:42:55.270 [Camel (camel-1) thread #6 - QueueReplyManager["TEST"]] TRACE org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.JmsReplyHelper: Using MessageSelector[JMSCorrelationID='CamelDummyJmsMessageSelector']
26-08-2024 13:42:55.862 [Camel (camel-1) thread #5 - JmsReplyManagerTimeoutChecker["TEST"]] TRACE org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap: Running purge task to see if any entries have been timed out
26-08-2024 13:42:55.862 [Camel (camel-1) thread #5 - JmsReplyManagerTimeoutChecker["TEST"]] TRACE org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap: There are 0 in the timeout map

In my case, I am using latest camel(4.7.0) & spring-boot(3.2.6) libraries

It seems like you have some config issue, in your jms, and to be more precise, the number of concurrent consumers to be used, i would enforce having only one.
Something like this :
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.ReplyManager;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.SharedQueueMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class CamelConfig {

    @Bean
    public JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration(CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory) {
        JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration();
        jmsConfiguration.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory);
        jmsConfiguration.setReplyToMaxConcurrentConsumers(1); // Ensure only one consumer
        return jmsConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsEndpoint jmsEndpoint(JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration) {
        JmsEndpoint jmsEndpoint = new JmsEndpoint();
        jmsEndpoint.setConfiguration(jmsConfiguration);
        return jmsEndpoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReplyManager replyManager(JmsEndpoint jmsEndpoint) {
        SharedQueueMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new SharedQueueMessageListenerContainer();
        listenerContainer.setConcurrentConsumers(1); // Ensure only one consumer
        listenerContainer.setIdleConsumerLimit(1); // Limit idle consumers
        listenerContainer.setIdleTaskExecutionLimit(1); // Limit idle task executions
        return new ReplyManager(jmsEndpoint, listenerContainer);
    }
}

